# How to use WMI to query IP address from specific NIC?

Tags: batch-file, ms-dos, wmi, wmic

I have a computer with two NICs. I'm trying to query the IP address of each NIC separately to use in BGInfo.

This [article](https://renjithmenon.com/how-to-set-bginfo-to-display-only-the-active-network-cards-ip-address/) describes how to query the IP address of only active network interfaces. It uses the following WMI query

```
SELECT IPAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled=True
```

However, I want to query each IP address separately by referencing the name of the NIC. I've tried the following query but it fails due to being invalid.

```
SELECT IPAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE Name=""
```

How do I use WMI to query the IP address of a specific NIC? There are few resources available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use WMI to query IP address from specific NIC?

You need to select one property to make this specific and the correct, like:
Description MAC Address IPAddress:

Get this from the command line and remove any unnecessary ones (in this example):

```
wmic nicconfig get macaddress,description|findstr /vb "Microsoft Bluetooth WAN Miniport"
```

- In the output of the command, select the mac address already distinguishing which is Ethernet and which is Wi-Fi if applicable, if not, use the ‘interfaces’ that apply to your case:

```
Description                               MACAddress
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller        E1-4B-AF-9F-FE-D2
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165       2C-04-0E-50-F0-E5
```

- Add this each mac address accorded with this query in BGInfo:

```
IP ehernet: 
SELECT IPAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where MACAddress='E1-4B-AF-9F-FE-D2'

IP wireless:
SELECT IPAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where MACAddress='2C-04-0E-50-F0-E5'
```

---

[image]

---

---

- Results:

---

---

[image]

---

**Obs.:** These are the devices removed for this example (the unnecessary ones):

```
wmic nicconfig get macaddress,description|findstr /vb "Microsoft Bluetooth WAN Miniport"

Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
WAN Miniport (SSTP)
Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Apple Mobile Device Ethernet
```

---

**Note:** For purposes of illustration, I used the same mac address in both requests, which explains the same ip in both, also the mac address came from one **[fake mac address generate](https://miniwebtool.com/mac-address-generator/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can query like this to get the IP address of specific network adapter:

```
wmic path win32_networkadapterconfiguration where "IPEnabled=True" get caption,ipaddress | find /i "ADAPTER NAME"
```

For all adapters (with IP enabled):

```
wmic path win32_networkadapterconfiguration where "IPEnabled=True" get caption,ipaddress
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Query not in form "SELECT xxx FROM ...". Any idea as to why this would happen?